# Checking if database connected to Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, connection

I try to connect to [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) database using `mysql.connector.connect()`, I checked if all arguments passed to function are ok and they are. I want the output of this code to confirm the connection made to database. I run this in `PyCharm` and nothing happens, just waiting for something... MySQL
Workbench is all set up, I mean the connection is tested and it works well.

```py
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="Asdf124#")
if (db):
    print("connected")
else:
    print("fail")
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239480/how-to-check-if-a-mysql-connection-is-open-in-python) Answers your question ?

Answer (score 0):

As from examples in the docs:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
  cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott',
                                database='employ')
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
    print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
  elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
    print("Database does not exist")
  else:
    print(err)
else:
  cnx.close()
```

This is the proper way to handle exceptions when connecting to the database.