# MySql.connect, "connect_timeout" how to handle?

Tags: python, mysql

The method "connect" of MySql driver for python has an argument "connect_timeout". But it's not mentioned anywhere what exception is caused when the timeout occurs **specified by an argument "connect_timeout"** or how to handle it. Any information?

Comment: Based off of what you are telling me there isn't much to work with.  However, something that might help is that next time you get this error, hop into mysql and run `show full processlist;` maybe there is a query that is taking forever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: MySQL: Handling timeouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568508/python-mysql-handling-timeouts)